# What happens if registerDoMC() is used with a number greater than the number of cores?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I'm using a laptop with a 4-core CPU, but somehow using `registerDoMC(20)` seems to work as if I had 20 cores available:

```r
library(tictoc)
library(doMC)

detectCores()
#> [1] 4

registerDoMC(20)
tic()
a <- foreach(i = 1:20) %dopar% {
  Sys.sleep(1)
  i
}
toc()
#> 1.084 sec elapsed
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

How is this explained? If I only have 4 cores available, how were the 20 jobs ran in 1 second + some overhead?

At first, I thought I `registerDoMC()` would return an error for anything greater than `detectCores()`, but since it didn't and I had this surprising result, I think I misunderstood what happens under the hood in `foreach`.

Comment: Because the underlying OS is a multi-tasking operating system, it already has way more processes running than you have cores available. It just means you have more instances and will not be able to benefit from having all R sub-processes running in a core simultaneously. Typically the improvement in overall performance with increasing the number of simultaneous cores goes down when you exceed the number of cores, so your overall speed-gain above ncores is generally not worth the effort. Further, if there is "large-ish data", the time to xfer data between processes is non-trivial.

Comment: My practice has typically been to do "ncores minus 1", leaving 1 core for basic OS-admin stuff ... though even then I've occasionally maxed out and still seen benefits. So while you will likely not break anything by using more processes than you have cores available, I suggest never exceeding it, you are unlikely (in R) to see any performance gains from doing so (and likely a performance penalty).

Comment: If I understood correctly, if my example had some actual processing that took 1 second rather than `sys.sleep(1)`, then it would take more time to run, i.e., my example was oversimplified enough to cause a misinterpretation?

Comment: Assuming you have a cluster "standing by" (no process startup-costs) and that your data-transfer requirements are modest to negligible, then running the job on 20 processes may take about the same time as 4, give-or-take. If you are timing from cluster-start and/or if your data transfer is significant, then 4 may be faster than 20 overall.

Comment: Thank you, that really helped clear the misconceptions I had. If you want, you may write that first comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the underlying OS is a multi-tasking operating system, it already has way more processes running than you have cores available. It just means you have more instances and will not be able to benefit from having all R sub-processes running in a core simultaneously. Typically the improvement in overall performance with increasing the number of simultaneous cores goes down when you exceed the number of cores, so your overall speed-gain above ncores is generally not worth the effort. Further, if there is "large-ish data", the time to xfer data between processes is non-trivial.

My practice has typically been to do "ncores minus 1", leaving 1 core for basic OS-admin stuff ... though even then I've occasionally maxed out and still seen benefits. So while you will likely not break anything by using more processes than you have cores available, I suggest never exceeding it, you are unlikely (in R) to see any performance gains from doing so (and likely a performance penalty).